# JavaScript Array of Self-Contained Functions access to index of self

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, self-contained

Given an array of self-contained JavaScript functions is there a way to access their respective indexes from within the function code? I would like to avoid having to hard-code those indexes in the function code:

```
var testArr = [
(function(){return 0})(),
(function(){return 'how to return/access ARRAY INDEX (=1)??'})()
]


console.log(testArr[0]) // 0
console.log(testArr[1]) // how to return/access ARRAY INDEX (=1)??
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish (as a larger goal)?

Comment: There needs to be an IF statement in the function code using array index of that function (which function was run last time)

Comment: Why don't you store whichever function was run last time in another variable, e.g., `var lastIndex;`. Then, whenever you call a function, you can update its value.

Comment: Yes, I do store which fn was run. How would I write in function[1] for example "if (lastIndex === 1)" where "1" is self-index?

Comment: I'm still interested in what your larger goal is. Why are you storing these self-executing functions in an array? There might be an easier way to approach whatever you're trying to accomplish. If you explained in a little more detail what exactly you're trying to do (besides access the array index of a given function), we might be able to help you further.

Comment: It's part of a rather complex (for posting the code here) mechanism that dynamically generates form fields depending on which object a user selects in GUI. Those functions return sets of form fields. There is a large set of those functions and each GUI object has a subset of them. Each of those functions in turn performs different tasks on what a user did with form fields. That's where I need to know array index of the function inside the function. All works well there except I have to hard-code those values. I'm ready to consider object vs. array (associative array) if that would help.

Comment: perhaps you could use a closure with a generator function (not referring to the ES6 harmony proposal): `var gen = function (index, fn) { return fn; }`. Now, you can call `var bettetFn = gen(5, myFunction)`, and `betterFn` will be aware of the value of `index`.

Comment: perhaps this is most elegant: fn code "(function(idx){return idx})" and call it like so "testArr[0](0)"

Answer (score 0):

Having analyzed different options I think this one is the most appropriate (without immediate invocation of self-contained function + passing array index into function arguments)

```
var testArr = [
(function(idx){return idx}),
(function(idx){return idx * 2})
]

console.log(testArr[0](0)) // 0
console.log(testArr[1](1)) // 2
```